# GSON equivalent for @JsonIgnoreProperties in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, gson

In Jackson you can ignore the properties by giving annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at class level and the properties which are not in the actual JSON are not serialized/deserialized from/to the Java class. What is the equivalent of it if we are using GSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a similar effect with the GSON `@Expose` annotation using `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`.

E.g.

```
 public class User {
     @Expose private String firstName;
     @Expose(serialize = false) private String lastName;
     @Expose (serialize = false, deserialize = false) private String emailAddress;
     private String password;
 }
```

If you use `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()` with the above class, then the `toJson()` and `fromJson()` methods will completely ignore the password field as it doesn't have an `@Expose` annotation.

(Note you also get finer-grained control here as you can control whether GSON serializes/deserializes fields as well).

Reference: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Gson-s-Expose

Comment: Yes, but it's working just with the opposite logic, not so comfortable if I have to exclude just one field over hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

In GSON, you can also declare the field as `transient`. It will have the same effect as opposite to marking other fields as `@Expose`. But, you will not have finer grained control of serialization/deserialization as that of `@Expose`. However, if you have 100s of fields spanned across multiple classes, and you only need to exclude one field, it is far more convenient to mark the field as `transient`. Moreover, this works on the default setting of GSON. E.g.

```
public class User {
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     private String emailAddress;
     private transient String password;
 }
```

Reference: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#finer-points-with-objects