# @jsonIgnore annotation is not working

Tags: java, json, pojo

I am using `@JsonIgnore` property to ignore some attributes in pojo, but these fields are not ignore in json response after parsing json using Gson library please help.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class RideInvite extends RideInviteOld  implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3729010679180341959L;


    private double newFare = -1;
    @JsonIgnore
    private long prefPickupDropId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String pickupLandmark;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String dropLandmark;
}
```

using following code to parse

```
 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        jsonText = gson.toJson(msgObject);
```

Response after parsing

```
{"newFare":-1.0,"prefPickupDropId":2,"savePickupDropPoints":false,"pickupDropBasedOnTraffic":true,"allowFareChange":true}
```

here prefPickupDropId and savePickupDropPoints are json ignored but still value attribute is present in json text

I can not use @Expose for fields because my project is build in such away that ignoring fields which are not required json ignore and same pojos are using for preparing http response. This was working fine earlier but recently I am facing this issue

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON equivalent for @JsonIgnoreProperties in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115624/gson-equivalent-for-jsonignoreproperties-in-jackson)

Comment: If an user answered your question please also accept his answer [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not than please specify what remains unanswered, this is a really crucial part of StackOverflow, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**Approach1:**
Instead of using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` you should use
[com.google.gson.annotations.Expose](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) to achieve your requirement.

Here is working code snippet -

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class RideRecord implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private double newFare = -1;

    private long prefPickupDropId;

    private String pickupLandmark;

    private String dropLandmark;

    public RideRecord(double newFare, long prefPickupDropId, String pickupLandmark, String dropLandmark) {
        super();
        this.newFare = newFare;
        this.prefPickupDropId = prefPickupDropId;
        this.pickupLandmark = pickupLandmark;
        this.dropLandmark = dropLandmark;
    }

}
```

use the following code to parse:

```
RideRecord msgObject = new RideRecord(-1.0, 2, "sfo", "powell bart station");
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        String jsonText = gson.toJson(msgObject);
        System.out.println(jsonText);
```

It will give output:

> {"newFare":-1.0}

because only `newFare` is the field which is exposed.
you can play with the `@Expose` attribute to meet your requirements.

**Approach2:**

> If you don't want to use `@Expose` then also you can achieve your
>   requirement by just creating `Gson` object as below -

```
RideRecord msgObject = new RideRecord(-1.0, 2, "sfo", "powell bart station");
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {

                return fieldAttributes.getName().equals("prefPickupDropId") || fieldAttributes.getName().equals("pickupLandmark") || fieldAttributes.getName().equals("dropLandmark");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        Gson gson = builder.create();
        String jsonText = gson.toJson(msgObject);
        System.out.println(jsonText);
```

In this case also you will get the same output :

> {"newFare":-1.0}

Comment: but in my project i can not use this because 1. I can not change all my pojos to @Expose and need to use same pojo for http response also this was working earlier , can you please help me with using json ignore any depedencies etc

Comment: @Rakesh, can you use transient like as below-? 
private double newFare = -1;
private transient long prefPickupDropId;
private transient String pickupLandmark;
private transient String dropLandmark;
expected result you can get in this case as well.

Comment: @Rakesh, does my answer meet your requirement?

Comment: @Rakesh, if you have any limitation to use `transient` then you can try the simple solution explained above in Approach2

Answer (score 1):

You're using Jackson with GSON and those are too separate frameworks.

One of the approaches is to initialize Gson to exclude fields that do not have the expose annotation.

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();`

Then mark every field you need to use with the `@Expose` annotation:

ex:

`class MyClass {
  @Expose public String name;
}`